# split a string to check the first character in c++

Tags: c++, string, cin

I need to split a string which is (string) (int) (string) (int). I have this while which keeps on going untill the first string is '#'. But whenever I want to enter the '#' to finish the while, i have to enter the entire string, # (int) (string) (int). How can I code it so I only need to enter # to finish and not the entire string? 
This is the code i have:

```
void afegirEquips(EquipLliga & e) {
// Pre: --
// Post: Afegeix els equips entrats per teclat amb els seus gols al vector d'equips i calcula els seus punts

    string equipA, equipB;
    int golsA=0, golsB=0, n=0, cerca;
    e.n=0;
    cin >> equipA;
    cin >> golsA >> equipB >> golsB;          // Entra el primer equip per poder comprobar la condicio del 'while'
    while(equipA!=FI) {
        if(e.n>0) {
            cin >> equipA;
            cin >> golsA >> equipB >> golsB;      // Entra tots els equips menys el primer
        }
        cerca=cercaEquip(e,equipA);
        int posA=0;
        if(cerca==-1) {                      // Guarda la informacio del primer equip entrat i actualitza els gols i punts
            e.t[n].nomEquip=equipA;          // en el cas que l'equip sigui nou a la llista d'equips
            e.t[n].golsf=golsA;
            e.t[n].golsc=golsB;
           if(golsA>golsB) e.t[n].punts=e.t[n].punts+3;
           if(golsA<golsB) e.t[n].punts=e.t[n].punts;
           if(golsA==golsB) e.t[n].punts=e.t[n].punts+1;
            e.n++;
            n++;
        }
        else {                                              // Guarda la informacio del primer equip entrat i actualitza els gols i punts
            e.t[cerca].golsf=e.t[cerca].golsf+golsA;        // en el cas que l'equip ja existeixi a la llista d'equips
            e.t[cerca].golsc=e.t[cerca].golsc+golsB;
            if(golsA>golsB) e.t[cerca].punts=e.t[cerca].punts+3;
            if(golsA<golsB) e.t[cerca].punts=e.t[cerca].punts;
            if(golsA==golsB) e.t[cerca].punts=e.t[cerca].punts+1;
        }
        cerca=cercaEquip(e,equipB);
        int posB=0;
        if(cerca==-1) {                                     // Guarda la informacio del segon equip entrat i actualitza els gols i punts
            e.t[n].nomEquip=equipB;                         // en el cas que l'equip sigui nou a la llista d'equips
            e.t[n].golsf=golsB;
            e.t[n].golsc=golsA;
            if(golsA>golsB) e.t[n].punts=e.t[n].punts;
            if(golsA<golsB) e.t[n].punts=e.t[n].punts+3;
            if(golsA==golsB) e.t[n].punts=e.t[n].punts+1;
            e.n++;
            n++;
        }
        else {                                              // Guarda la informacio del segon equip entrat i actualitza els gols i punts
            e.t[cerca].golsf=e.t[cerca].golsf+golsB;        // en el cas que l'equip ja existeixi a la llista d'equips
            e.t[cerca].golsc=e.t[cerca].golsc+golsA;
            if(golsA>golsB) e.t[cerca].punts=e.t[cerca].punts;
            if(golsA<golsB) e.t[cerca].punts=e.t[cerca].punts+3;
            if(golsA==golsB) e.t[cerca].punts=e.t[cerca].punts+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't mind the rest of the code, it's just the cin that matters. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop should be changed so that you only read in the other inputs after you check `equipA`.

```
  cin >> equipA;
  while(equipA!=FI) {
      cin >> golsA >> equipB >> golsB;
      //...
      cin >> equipA;
  }
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot I thought this was a lot more difficult than it actually is!